# Pegando informação de um JSON e salvando no SQL Server usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sql-server, rest

Eu tenho esse código, que retorna as informações que eu quero e mostra na página.

Agora eu precisaria salvar essas informações num banco de dados SQL Server, como isso seria possível?

Esta sendo bem difícil para mim, visto que nunca trabalhei com API, JSON nem JavaScript antes.

```js
function makeServiceCall() {     
  var url = "http://widsservicedev.yaharasoftware.com/WidsService/JSON/GetPortagePrograms/?apikey=104043F0-9C24-4957-879D-046868973CC4&callback";
  
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    //var myArray = [];
    //myArray[0] = data;
    parseProgramData(data, url);
  });     
}

function parseProgramData(jsonData, url) {  
  $("#dataHeader").empty();
  $("#dataHeader").append('<b>' + url + '</b>');
  
  var programUL = document.getElementById("programUL");  

  for (var pgmIndex = 0; pgmIndex < jsonData.Programs.length; pgmIndex++) {     
    var pgmLi = document.createElement("li");
    var program = jsonData.Programs[pgmIndex];
    var programInfoRevision = program.ProgramInfoRevisions[0];
    var numberTitle = programInfoRevision.ProgramNumber + " " + programInfoRevision.ProgramTitle;
    pgmLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numberTitle));
    programUL.appendChild(pgmLi);     
    
    var linebreak = document.createElement("br");
    pgmLi.appendChild(linebreak);
    
    var poLabel = document.createElement("label");
    poLabel.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Program Outcomes"));
    poLabel.classList.add("headerLabel");     
    pgmLi.appendChild(poLabel);     
    
    var pgmOutcomeUL = document.createElement("UL");
    pgmLi.appendChild(pgmOutcomeUL);
    
    for (var poIndex = 0; poIndex < program.ProgramOutcomes.length; poIndex++) {     
      var poLi = document.createElement("li");
      poLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(program.ProgramOutcomes[poIndex].Description));
      pgmOutcomeUL.appendChild(poLi);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.bodyFrame {
  margin: 40px;
}

.headerLabel {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="bodyFrame">
      <h2 style="text-align:center;">WIDS JSON Retrieval Example</h2>
      
      <button type="button" onclick="makeServiceCall()">Retrieve JSON Data</button>
      <br /><br />
            
      <label class="headerLabel">Programs</label>
      <ul id="programUL"></ul>
    <div>
  </body>

  <footer>  
  </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu nao tenho muito conhecimento em JavaScript, na verdade esse é o primeiro projeto que uso javascript... tenho mais conhecimento em JAva , seria possivel algo em Java para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Nesse caso, como na maioria dos casos, o JavaScript está sendo executado no **lado do cliente**, no navegador do usuário que está acessando o seu website, mais especificamente.

Para salvar dados no SQL Server você precisaria ter algum código sendo executado no **lado do servidor**, como ASP.NET ou PHP, por exemplo.

Veja essas respostas no SO<sup>EN</sup>:

> [How to save html form data to sql db using javascript or jquery - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23759449/8133067)
>   [javascript - How to use KnockoutJS to save data into SQL database? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45093079/8133067)

**Edição**

O [Máttheus Spoo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/110001) lembrou bem, nos comentários, que se o autor da pergunta já está usando JavaScript, uma boa opção de código no lado do servidor seria também o **Node.js**.

O Node.js é um interpretador de código JavaScript multiplataforma e de código aberto, construído a partir do mecanismo JavaScript V8 do Google Chrome, cujo objetivo, resumidamente, é executar código JavaScript fora de um navegador, portanto, muito usado para criar scripts do lado do servidor.

O Node.js tem uma arquitetura assíncrona orientada a eventos e foi projetado para criar aplicativos de rede escalonáveis, e é usado principalmente para construir servidores da Web.

Com o Node.js seria possível então escrever código no lado do servidor, com JavaScript, para gravar dados no SQL Server. Veja essa resposta no SO<sup>EN</sup>:

> [node.js - send Data to SQL DataBase with nodeJs - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47888792/8133067)

Fontes:

> [Node.js - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)
>   [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/)

Comment: Já que ele está tentando fazer em javascript e já tem algum conhecimento sobre javascript, valeria a pena ter apontado Node.js, não?

Comment: Boa @MáttheusSpoo, vou adicionar sua dica na resposta!